# Как сделать онлайн редактор статей?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Суть: на сайте есть кучка статей. Нужно чтобы была кнопочка/ссылочка при нажатии на которую, div, содержащий статью, заменялся на textarea. В котором была бы эта статься с html тегами. И кнопка "сохранить".
И, желательно, чтобы все это происходило без перезагрузки страницы...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="articles">
    <div class="article">
        <p>текст</p>
        <p>текст</p>
        <b>подпись</b>
    </div>
    <span class="article_edit">edit</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.article_edit').toggle(
        function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var ar = t.closest('.articles').find('.article').eq(0);
            ar.html('<textarea cols="50" rows="10">'+ar.html()+'</textarea>');
            t.html('save');
        }, function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var ar = t.closest('.articles').find('.article textarea').eq(0);
            t.html('loading...');
            /*
            $.post('saveArticle.php', {'text': ar.val()}, function(data){
                t.closest('.articles').find('.article').eq(0).html(data); //php скрипт должен печатать сообщение или ошибку
                t.html('edit');
            });
            */
            t.closest('.articles').find('.article').eq(0).html(ar.val());
            t.html('edit');
        }
    );
</script>
```

Разберетесь, что к чему?

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Постараюсь разобраться...